# Cannot browse websites in my Windows computer

Tags: windows-10, browser, internet

My Windows 10 computer is behaving very strangely: whenever I enter some websites, such as GMail, as well as many others, I see strange text like this:

[image]

The same happens in all browsers I have on this computer - Firefox, Chrome and Edge - so it is probably not a browser problem.

On the other hand, on another (Ubuntu) computer that I have connected to the same router, I can view all websites just fine; so it is probably not a problem with my network.

EDIT: I disabled the extensions and add-ons in all browsers (in Edge I had no extensions since I barely use it). I also opened an Incognito window in Chrome, but it did not help.
The problem started in all browsers at the same time, so it probably is not related to extensions that I installed.

It seemed like a virus, so I ran a complete virus scan (by Windows defender), and it found some threats that it considered "Low" severity:

- PUA:Win32/InstallCore
- PUA:Win32/Presenoker

I removed them, but I do not know if they are related in any way to the problem.

What else can I do?

Comment: I would recommend that you (a) disable any/all addons for all three browsers, and if that fixes the problem, add them back one at a time to find the one that's breaking things. If that doesn't help, (b) try doing a reset-all-browser-settings-to-default; if that doesn't work either, (c) run a full malware scan on the computer, probably best by booting from a LiveCD or LiveUSB.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I disabled the extensions and add-ons in all browsers (in Edge I had no extensions since I barely use it). I also opened an Incognito window in Chrome, but it did not help. The problem started in all browsers at the same time, so it probably is not related to extensions that I installed.

Comment: Another thing to do on a Windows system, after you've done all of the above, is to start up an Administrator command prompt, and run `sfc /scannow`. This will check for corrupted system files, and attempt to refresh them.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thanks! After several scans (by Windows defender, and another anti-virus that I installed) the problem went away. I still do not know if it was a virus or another kind of corruption.